# Prevent Bootstrap Menu going Behind Footer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've designed a Page who has Top Navigation, Slider and Footer. it looks fine on Desktop but when we open/Expand the Menu on Mobile Device, the Menu is going behind the Footer.

Please note that we cannot add extra White Space between Slider and Footer to prevent this as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20398549/bootstrap-footer-hiding-contents-above-it)

Following is the Screenshot from Mobile Device:

[image]

How can we resolve this?
please help

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Increase the z-index of your dropdown menu in css. Like if your dropdown menu is something like this:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <ul>
    <li><a>Home</a></li>
    <li><a>About Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You just have to make sure the z-index of your dropdown is greater than your footer element. You can try increasing z-index of your dropdown element something like this:

```
.dropdown {
    z-index: 999
 }
```

Make sure your dropdown has a position other than static for z-index to be effective, also the z-index value that you give it should be greater than the z-index value of your footer element.